# Trouble with returning value from function

Tags: javascript

Please, look at this code and tell me why doesn't work? i think that there is a problem with return in function. Thanks for all replays.

```
var movie1 = {
    title: "Buckaroo Banzai",
    genre: "Cult classic",
    rating: 5,
    showtimes: ["1:00pm", "3:00pm", "7:00pm"]
}

function getNextShowing(movie) {
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < movie.showtimes.length; i++) {
        var showtime = getTimeFromString(movie.showtimes[i]);
        if ((showtime - now) > 0) {
            return "Next showing of " + movie.title + " is " + movie.showtimes[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function getTimeFromString(timeString) {
    var theTime = new Date();
    var time = timeString.match(/(\d+)(?::(\d\d))?\s*(p?)/);
    theTime.setHours( parseInt(time[1]) + (time[3] ? 12 : 0) );
    theTime.setMinutes( parseInt(time[2]) || 0 );
    return theTime.getTime();
}

var nextShowing = getNextShowing(movie1);
alert(nextShowing);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line of code:

```
if ((showtime - now) > 0)
```

`(showtime - now)` is always less than zero therefore the `getNextShowing()` function always returns `null`;

Comment: @user1033392:) Saying thanks is not sufficient. You must vote this answer up and consider marking it as your accepted answer, if this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the above code, and it only returned me a null when the time in my computer is greater than or equal to 7:00pm.

Otherwise it works fine. Try changing the timing of the showtimes array, so that they are ahead of current time in your computer. Or try running it during the morning :).
I think that is all you need to do.